# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS+NVidia RTX 6000+SSSD: System Menu Hang/Freeze

Tags: nvidia, freeze, system, sssd

This is an odd one or at least it seems to be to me.

I have a Precision 3660 with no built-in graphics/Intel graphics running a AMD CPU. This additionally has a NVidia RTX 6000 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The system is further using a realm join and SSSD. Everything is perfect working order beyond one thing: the System Menu in the top right freezes or hangs for ~20-30 seconds when clicked or opened when logged in as an AD/domain account; local accounts do not experience the issue. The menu then becomes available after that freeze and works fine or is accessible for Power actions or similar items available from that menu. If the menu is closed and then re-opened, the issue returns.

The syslog and other logs have all been investigated and I am not really able to find any clue as to the cause. The only item of note is the 'auth.log' has a gap that appears during this hang that  coincides with it. If the card is pulled and replaced with an AMD Radeon or similarly less high-spec'ed card, the issue does not occur.

This would seem to indicate to me that something is occurring when accessing the menu that is some sort of authorization or similar but I have no clue as to what it may be. This happens for accounts that can use SUDO or not or become root that are AD/domain accounts. Further, if I install and use xRDP, the issue does not occur when the NVidia card is installed while RDP'ed to the system. I have tried various driver permutations as well for the card between late 400's up to the 530 driver version of various proprietary and non-proprietary versions.

I am at a bit of a loss on this one so if anyone has some ideas on where might be a good place to investigate this issue's cause or source beyond the card being a PITA, I welcome suggestions.

Comment: As it turns out, the issue is present on any graphics card and as mentioned, is only present in logged-on, AD/domain accounts. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The specific problem is the menu hanging and I suppose my question is if anyone has suggestions on where best to search out this problem. I mean, what log file generates info besides syslog when a menu is clicked, such as the System Menu? I have run out of ideas and will gladly provide more info. This is a realm joined system on SSSD with no major restrictions on it